# Copy all content inside of subfolders to the main folder?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

- Files/0/Image1.png
- Files/0/Image2.png
- Files/0/Image3.png
- Files/1/Image4.png
- Files/1/Image5.png
- Files/1/Image6.png

All the way to 1000.

I need to get all the contents of the subfolders into the directory "Files", so there's no subfolders anymore. Just the parent folder which holds all the files.

Is there any easy way to do this? Except for C/P'ing 1000 folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Files" folder, make a search for "*.*" (meaning all files with all extensions).
This search will return all the files in all folders, and from there you can cut all files (and leave the folders out) and paste them in "Files" folder.